# Adding content to Liferay via API

Tags: java, api, content-management-system, liferay

I am starting using Liferay Portal and I have two basic needs which I would like to achieve with Liferay.

1. Is there a posibility to add content to CMS through API level? I would like to insert some data "from code".
2. More important. How to achieve such situation that for every created user there will be its own homepage generated with some predefined template elements on it?

I have tried to Google something so far, but I did not find it helpful. Maybe some keywords?

---

After some analysis of documentation devoted to services and ServiceBuilder I realized that it is not what I want.

Let me show an example based on Websphere.
In Websphere we have bunch of EJB components available to perform some actions, exchange information with portal, easy to use. Isn't there any similar mechanism in Liferay not involving web services?

Answer (score 4):

My recommendation for this kind of question is to take a look at the sevencogs-hook sourcecode. The structure of this hook is basically just a long script that runs once, setting up a complete demo site with users, sites, pages, content etc. The code runs once (after the first deployment) and then never again. There are no (obvious) conditionals, no context to understand etc.

You can basically just step through everything and - in that process - understand how content (and pages, images, blog posts, etc.) are created and positioned on pages in Liferay.

This hook accesses the Java API, a very similar API is available through Webservices. Basically all of Liferay's portlets also use the same API to do their business.

Edit: Additional information to keep this answer valuable/current: Sevencogs is discontinued, but still available in old releases (source & binary). The API has slightly changed, so compiling/running it will need a bit of work. [James Falkner has blogged](https://www.liferay.com/de/web/james.falkner/blog/-/blogs/7cogs-is-dead-long-live-7cogs-) about the leftovers and lessons learnt - those snippets are extracted from sevencogs and contain the relevant code pieces to work with the API.

Comment: As of Liferay 6.2 also some of the old APIs (mentioned in the blog post) are deprecated (like JournalTemplateLocalServiceUtil). Instead, the Dynamic Data Mapping framework (DDM) is used.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [this page from the documentation](http://www.liferay.com/de/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/administration/-/ai/liferay-services-oriented-architectu-4): It smells like a SOAP interface (they mention some sort of *document uploader* service and I've read *axis*).

You'll find some url examples that should give a list of available webservices.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand well. Did you mean that those "programatic" activities can be achieved by executing some webservices given by Liferay?

Comment: That's how I understand it. Implement SOAP clients and use the liferay webservices to add content (from anywhere). Have a look at apache axis (library) and the tool soapUI (for playing around with the liferay services)

Answer (score 1):

For number 1, you can use the one of the:

```
JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.addArticle()
```

methods to programmatically add Liferay Web Content from a portlet. If you download the Liferay Portal Source you can see the structure of these methods.

For number 2, can create page templates with preconfigured portlets on them (through the Plugins-SDK), and then use the API to programmatically create the pages using one of the:

```
LayoutLocalServiceUtil.addLayout()
```

methods.

If you have any more speific questions about these comment back, and I hope this helps!